# Get highest counter values from a set of counters in redis

Tags: redis

**Use case:**

I am implementing a rate limiter for a web application. For every incoming HTTP request I increment a redis counter where the IP address is the key. Additionally I set an expire with a 30min TTL to avoid a memory leak.

**The problem:**

Now I've got thousands of entries and I'd like to get those entries which have the highest counter values. How can I do that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One option could be to use a redis [Sorted Set](https://redis.io/topics/data-types#Sorted-sets) and have the score to be the requests count, so for increasing the count you can use [ZINCRBY](https://redis.io/commands/zincrby) and to get the top *N* you can use [ZRANGE](https://redis.io/commands/zrange).

New request:

```
> ZINCRBY requests 1 10.0.0.1
```

Get top N:

```
> ZRANGE requests -5 -1 WITHSCORES
```

Downside is you will not be able to set a timeout per IP, but you could overcome that by separating the requests in different sorted sets by using different keys for each timeout period.

For example, if you want to count the requests for each day, instead of using the same key string **"requests"**, you can construct the key to be something like **"requests-*date*"**:

```
> ZINCRBY requests-19/01/25 1 10.0.0.1
> EXPIREAT requests-19/01/25 1516924800
```

Comment: That's exactly one solution I had in mind too, I wish it could be rolling instead of a requestdate, but it seems like there is no simple solution with Redis possible to overcome that.